# jQuery object not supported

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I have the following issues when the site is checked in IE7 and 8 (9 is fine)

Object doesn't support this property or method

When I check in the console it points to:

```
 call_1 = $('.call_1 span'),
```

I don't see any mistakes, could it be related to the function using the variable "call_1"?

Comment: Have you tried `jQuery('.call_1 span')` to make sure it's not an issue with the "$" alias?

Comment: What's the rest of that section of code? Just wondering why it has a comma at the end of it and whether it's doing anything else.

Comment: @Greg it's just a long list of variables declared in the same way as call_1..

Comment: maybe the , ?? IE7-8 doesnt like , in the end of a code-listing (other browsers ignore them)

Comment: just to give you an idea this is how list is a bit longer though...

Comment: champion = $('#ch'),
   skim = $('#sk'),
   pour  = $('#po'),
   box_all = $('#pr, #po, #ch, #sk');
   form = $('.form'),
   call_1 = $('.call_1 span'),
   call_2 = $('.call_2 span'),
   call_3 = $('.call_3 span'),
   call_4 = $('.call_4 span'),
   overlay = $('.x_ov'),
   overlay2 = $('#overlay_2'),
   overlay3 = $('#overlay_3'),
   overlay6 = $('#overlay_6'),

Comment: You need a `var` keyword after every `;`, there's one before `form` and add one in at the very start too if you don't have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `;` before `form = $('.form')` to `,`

Also, replace the last comma with a semi-colon.